# Not Showing Rich Snippet Rating

Tags: code-snippets, rating

Snippet test link: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=www.oyuntc.com/hay-day.html

In the example turns out the stars but the stars do not appear in google search. What could cause a've tried all the codes I could not get any results.

Comment: I have the same problem, and no solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be content-related issue: mark-up is fine, but google don't like your content. Mark-up is just recommendation, Google makes decision on its own. Try to make your entire page mark-up make more structured.

Also, try to make structure as Product - Review: [Google Search with Rating Stars (schema.org)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841593/google-search-with-rating-stars-schema-org?rq=1)

Comment: I also can't see markup indicating product title and product itself. It is needed for google to understand for whom this rating belongs to